# PYTHON: Multiprocessing quirks (OR: How do coordinate these threads?)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have been challenged.
I am unsure how to use multiprocessing without jython or cython (or some other IronPython whatsahoosie), and have opted to use Threads for my multicore CentOS program.
It reads a set of text files and outputs to a dictionary (defined by hfreq={} on the outside of the defined functions).  If I have it sleep, it runs (terribly slowly, seemingly on one core) and works fine.

Additionally, I do not know how to have it wait until both threads are done to actually output to file (other than the sleep.time part, which completely defeats the purpose of speed)

EXAMPLE:

```
hfreq={}
[INSERT TEXT FILE ARRAYS HERE, RESPECTIVELY filenames0[] and filenames1[]]
def count():
    some code here that writes frequency to hfreq
def count1():
    some code here that writes frequency to hfreq as well, but using filenames1
t1=Thread(target=count,args())
t2=Thread(target=count1,args())
t1.start()
t2.start()
time.sleep(15) #No other known way to prevent the following from running immediately
list=hfreq.items()
list.sort()
Output=Open('Freq.txt', 'w')
[for statement that writes to file]
Output.close()
```

And that is where it ends.  If I run the program with no threading classes (on its own), it gives about 10-14 seconds of runtime.  If I try the threading approach (halving the non-threading array between the two threads), I get BOTH THREADS running for 14 seconds (instead of the expected multi-core usage).
Thank you for reading this wall of text.  Please tell me if I can clarify.

Comment: In CPython, the [global interpreter lock (GIL)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) makes it impossible to use multiple cores at the same time with multiple threads. Use [multiple processes](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of multiple cores with CPython, you should use the `multiprocessing` module: it has many caveats but this is the sort of problem it's a relatively good fit for.

To wait until a thread is done, use `t.join()`.

Comment: What I meant here is that I cannot/want to avoid CPython and other libraries like that. Thank you for the help with the threads, though!

Comment: CPython is the default Python interpreter.